Jacobian Determinant of Orthogonal Conjugation of Matrices
I came across this problem while studying GOE Wigner matrices in random matrix theory. Note that a GEO matrix is a symmetric matrix whose off-diagonal entries are i.i.d with $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and whose diagonal entries are i.i.d with $\mathcal{N}(0,2)$.
For an $n \times n$ GOE matrix $M$ and an orthognal $n \times n$ matrix $O$, we have that $OMO^T$ is also a GOE matrix. The proof of this involves showing that $\mathbb{E}[f(M)] = \mathbb{E}[f(OMO^T)]$ for sufficiently nice $f$. In doing so, we must show that $d(M) = d(OMO^T)$, or in other words that the determinant of the Jacobian of the transormation that takes $M \rightarrow OMO^T$ is equal to $1$.
I've seen how to do this by using the fact that this transformation is an isometry and hence has the required Jacobian determinant. But I am wondering how one would calculate this explicitly? I'm not entirely sure what the Jacobian of this transformation even looks like.
Thanks

If $Y=OMO^T$ you can use vectorization to write $\def\vec{\operatorname{vec}}$ $\frac{\partial \vec Y}{\partial (\vec M)^T}=O \otimes O$. The Jacobian is $\def\vec{\operatorname{det}}$ $\det(O \otimes O)=\det(O)^n\det(O)^n=1$.

@TedBlack what do you mean by vectorization, I am not familiar with it in this context? Thanks

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics) for example. We are trying to produce the Jacobian matrix for a matrix function of a matrix and for this reason we convert $Y$ and $M$ to vectors using the $\mathrm{vec}$ operator.
